# Does signing a Unity3D Android App give security against decompilation?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Does signing a Unity3D Android App give some level of security against decompilation of the C# code?

Comment: if you want to protect against decompilation. you need an obfuscator. Problem is theres a lot of complexity surrounding the .net version unity uses. I have been working on it in my free time. but it isnt a simple process. Im raising money to afford to spend the time needed. http://igg.me/at/unity-obfuscator Check it out and share it. I will initially be releasing it for free if not permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, signing your application only identifies you as the developer of that application. It does not provide any added security against decompilation. You could go the route of obfuscation, if you wanted to, but even that only is an annoyance to those who are reverse engineering what you've done, and not really a guarantee for security.